# How to do proofs using CT for improper integrals with a vertical assymptote?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble with the following proof, can anyone please help me out?

Let a, b ∈ R with a < b. Suppose that f(x) and g(x) both have a vertical
asymptote at x = a. If $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ is convergent and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx$ is divergent, then prove that $\int_{a}^{b} (f(x)+g(x))dx$ is divergent.

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{A\to a^+}\int_{A}^{b} f(x) dx $
$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = \lim_{A\to a^+}\int_{A}^{b} g(x) dx $

Comment: We are given that $f$ is integrable.  If $g+f$ is integrable, then so is the sum $(g+f)-f=g$

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contrary that it were, then $\lim_{A\rightarrow a^{+}}\displaystyle\int_{A}^{b}(f(x)+g(x))dx$ exists and so is $\lim_{A\rightarrow a^{+}}\displaystyle\int_{A}^{b}(f(x)+g(x)-f(x))$ by a standard limit rule, then we get the convergence of $\lim_{A\rightarrow a^{+}}\displaystyle\int_{A}^{b}g(x)dx$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why did we add f(x) and then subtract it?

Comment: Considering $f+g$ is by the proof of contradiction. And then considering $f+g-f$ is because both $f+g$ and $f$ exists, and then $g$ exists, here is the contradiction.

Comment: But the contradiction is true, so wouldn't it mean the theorem is false?

Comment: What do you mean by the contradiction is true? The assumption is that, $g$ does not exist, and since we assume that the existence of $f+g$, we arrive at a contradiction, so that we cannot assume the existence of $f+g$, so we must conclude that $f+g$ does not exist.

Comment: Just curious, but I may have forgotten, can you remind me where the standard limit rule came from again?

Comment: $\lim u_{n}$ exists, $\lim v_{n}$ exists, then $\lim u_{n}-v_{n}$ exists.